# Regex And Stop At Whitespace

Tags: python, regex

I have strings looking like:

```
-(void) isItem:(bool)//arg//arg//arg//arg//arg rowIndex:(bool)//arg//arg//arg//arg//arg textLayout:(bool)//arg//arg//arg//arg//arg numberOfLines:(bool)//arg//arg//arg//arg//arg isPad:(bool)//arg//arg//arg//arg//arg {
```

I want to select only `//arg//arg//arg//arg//arg` in each of these strings (number of args will depend)

So I can replace it later and end up with:

```
-(void) configureForItem:(bool)ARG rowIndex:(bool)ARG textLayout:(bool)ARG numberOfLines:(bool)ARG isPad:(bool)ARG {
```

I tried: `\)\/\/[^/]*.*[^/]*{`
But it doesnt really work...
I think I need a similar regex, but to make it stop at first whitespace.

Thoughts?

Comment: Which language?

Comment: How about chopping the line up by whitespace and then running your regex?

Comment: @ctwheels I'll replace it with python re.sub

Comment: @Tripp Kinetics I need the whitespaces later, and really want to be able to clean it with one single regex re.sub

Comment: Use [`(?<=\))//\S+`](https://regex101.com/r/Vobnml/1)

Comment: @ctwheels Please put this in an answer and explain why it works but the OPs example does not. Significant features are the positive lookbehind and non-whitespace class. 12k rep should know better!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your regex `\)\/\/[^/]*.*[^/]*{` includes `.*` which matches whitespace characters (other than `\n`). This is causing your regex to return one result after the first `)//` and up to the last `{`

[See regex in use here](https://regex101.com/r/Vobnml/1)

```
(?<=\))//\S+
```

- `(?<=\))` Positive lookbehind ensuring what precedes is `)` (literally)
- `//` Matches `/` twice. Can be substitued with `/{2}` for a *very* slight performance boost
- `\S+` Matches any non-whitespace character one or more times